# QuerySet automatic/aspect filtering

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models, django-admin

I have a model which has an `active` field, and i want to filter out all records which are inactive basing on this field. Let's say:

```
Record(Model):
    active = BooleanField()
    ...
```

to filter them out i can do:

```
Record.objects(active=True)
```

But it is a general case and i want inactive records to be filtered out almost any time. What is the best way to follow DRY principle and do not filter every request i do manually like in example above and in meantime keep the ability to manage inactive records in admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) to achieve this task:

```
# First, define the Manager subclass.
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ActiveManager, self).get_query_set().filter(active=True)

# Then hook it into the Record model explicitly.
class Record(models.Model):
    active = BooleanField()

    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    active_objects = ActiveManager() # The specific manager.

#to filter for all active records you can do:
Record.active_objects.all()
```